# Why StringBuilder's delete shifts string to the left and does not delete the last character?

Tags: java

I'm new here.
I'm trying to figure out how to delete the last character in the string but I'm not succeeding.
I use my code - in StringBuilder.

For example I have a string of 'abcde'
i want to get after delete the first character - the String bcde
but i got the string bcdee.
All the time I keep deleting - the last character is not deleted
I want to delete the first character in the string and leave nothing at the end.

```
        StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder();
        test.append("abcde");
        test.deleteCharAt(0);
        test.deleteCharAt(0);
        test.deleteCharAt(0);
        test.deleteCharAt(0);
```

After running this code
I get: I want to get:

```
bcdee    bcde
cdeee    cde
deeee    de
eeeee    e
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce: `StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder(); test.append("abcde"); test.deleteCharAt(0); System.out.println(test);` prints "bcde"

Comment: How do you print out? If I use the `java.lang.StringBuilder` class and add a `System.out.println(test);` after your code it prints "e"

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support, when I look at DEBUG -I see that the string itself was not deleted at the end, I do not understand why.

Comment: @dustyeav Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: The `StringBuilder` doesn't overwrite trailing characters because it's not necessary. The `StringBuilder` contains a field `size` that records how long the valid content is. Everything in the character array after `size` characters is unimportant.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. As I state in my answer, it outputs what is expected to be outputted, without any additional `e` characters.

Comment: By "when I do DEBUG" do you mean "when I look at the private field in the StringBuilder"? If so, that's private for a reason. `StringBuilder` can do what it likes in terms of representation so long as the *public* API works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to figure out how to delete the last character in the string.

To delete the last character in a `String`:

```
String s = someString.substring(0, someString.length() - 1)
```

Note that a `String` is ummutable, so the above is *actually* creating a new `String`.

To remove the last character in a `StringBuilder`:

```
someStringBuilder.setLength(someStringBuilder.length() - 1);
```

You can also remove the last character using

```
someStringBuilder.deleteCharAt(someStringBuilder.length() - 1);
```

The above code fragments all assume that there *is* a last character to be removed.

---

Your code calls `deleteCharAt(0)`.  That deletes the first character not the last one.

---

But your example seems to require you to remove *duplicate* characters at the end of a string.  To do that, you need a loop:

```
pseudocode

while last character equals second to last character:
    remove last character
```

See if you can code that for yourself ...

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, when I do DEBUG - I still see the string without deleting in the end

Comment: You are probably misinterpreting the `StringBuilder` internal data structure.  Instead of using the debugger, try calling `StringBuilder.toString` and printing the result.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code:

```
    StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder();
    test.append("abcde");
    System.out.println(test);
    test.deleteCharAt(0);
    System.out.println(test);
    test.deleteCharAt(0);
    System.out.println(test);
    test.deleteCharAt(0);
    System.out.println(test);
    test.deleteCharAt(0);
    System.out.println(test);
```

outputs:

```
abcde
bcde
cde
de
```

which is correct, as expected, without any additional `e`s, as you mention it in the original question. So, try to figure out what you have additionally in your code that causes this.

---

> Why delete in StringBuilder shift string to left and doesn't delete the last character?

It shifts, because, by `test.deleteCharAt(0);`, you explicitly tell Java to *delete Char at* specific (`0`, in this case) index, hence the new String will not be starting with an empty character; however, it **should nt** and it **does not** remove the last character, and the last extra character is simply *never* appended (there is no extra `e`).

---

Apart from the `.setLength()` and `.subString()`, you can simply use the same `.deleteCharAt(int)` API and do as follows:

```
    StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder();
    test.append("abcde");
    System.out.println(test);
    test.deleteCharAt(test.length()-1);
    System.out.println(test);
    test.deleteCharAt(test.length()-1);
    System.out.println(test);
    test.deleteCharAt(test.length()-1);
    System.out.println(test);
    test.deleteCharAt(test.length()-1);
    System.out.println(test);
```